# Client side request to opengraph.io

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to use opengraph.io in the client side. They have docs for jQuery which I've based my code on:
https://www.opengraph.io/examples/jquery-opengraph-example/

```
      const url = 'http://cnet.com';
      const urlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(url);
      const apiKey = 'MY-KEY';
      const requestUrl = 'https://opengraph.io/api/1.1/site/' + urlEncoded + '?app_id=' + apiKey;
      fetch(requestUrl).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.body);
      });
```

The response I get from `res` appears to be successful but doenst have the data I need.

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://opengraph.io/api/1.1/site/http%3A%2F%2Fcnet.com?app_id=MY-KEY"
```

I tried logging out `res.body` but it just returns:

```
ReadableStream {locked: false}
```

I found a similar question here but the API seems to return `res.data` which isnt the case for me:

[How to get Open Graph meta from URL input on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634812/how-to-get-open-graph-meta-from-url-input-on-the-client-side)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `res.json()` to convert the ReadableStream into some JSON.

For example, with an invalid key, just to show the output:

```js
const url = 'http://cnet.com';
const urlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(url);
const apiKey = 'MY-KEY';
const requestUrl = 'https://opengraph.io/api/1.1/site/' + urlEncoded + '?app_id=' + apiKey;

fetch(requestUrl)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```